# How to group rows by sums in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to partition BigQuery table by sums of values equal some number
For example:
Values: `10, 11, 20, 53, 14, 15, 5`. It must be partitioned by sum of values equal 30 or first cumulative sum after 30. Like card game "black jack". When sum values it's not enough for 30 needs to take next value.
Expected output:

```js
name     value   total
   first part 
d        53      53
   second part
c        20      35
f        15
   third part
e        14      35
b        11
c        10
```

`5` - must stay out of selection cuz it is sum less then 30.

My query can count cumulative sums only. But how can I modify this to get expected output?

```js
SELECT name, value, SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY value) AS RunningTotal, 
FROM 
(SELECT "a" AS name, 10 AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT "b" AS name, 11 AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT "c" AS name, 20 AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT "d" AS name, 53 AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT "e" AS name, 14 AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT "f" AS name, 15 AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT "g" AS name, 5 AS value)
```

Comment: what defines order of evaluation? - in you sample data I see only candidate - `name` is it this one? at the same time, from expected result - it looks like order is `value desc` - please clarify

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant sorry for my English. I explained more details

Comment: Should the sum be calculated ordered by name or value? In other words, if ordered by name, **a**,**b** and **c** would be together. Then, **d** alone and, finally, **e**,**f** and **g** together. Is this right?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes value.